# Magento 2: List all products

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

I need some direction...

Within Magento 2, I am not finding exactly how to do a `getCollection()` that will allow me to see a list of all products.  I am developing an Rest API to allow me to get a list of products based on a defined set of attributes.  The code I have is the following:

```
class Inventory implements InventoryInterface {
    private $scopeConfig;
    private $product;

    public function __construct(
        Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    public function get($id = null) {
        $data = $this->product->create()->getCollection();
        $data->addFieldToFilter('status', 1);
        $data->addFieldToFilter('type_id', 'simple');

        if ($id) {
            $data->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $id);
        }

        return $data->getData();
    }
}
```

with this, I am getting back the XML, but I am missing how to be able to select additional attributes to display.

Please be gentle in your responses...  I am new to this list AND Magento 2, so feeling a little stupid at this point.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I was finally able to get this to work...  The code is as follows:

```
class Inventory implements InventoryInterface {
    private $scopeConfig;
    private $product;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $product
    ) {
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    public function get($id = null) {
        $data = $this->product->create();
        $data->addFieldToFilter('status', 1);
        $data->addFieldToFilter('type_id', 'simple');

        if ($id) {
            $data->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $id);
        }
        $data->addAttributeToSelect('price');
        return $data->load()->toArray();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone.  Thanks again for the assist Pradeep.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
class Inventory  extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {
    private $scopeConfig;
    private $product;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $product
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    public function get($id = null) {
        $data = $this->product->create();
        $data->addFieldToFilter('status', 1);
        $data->addFieldToFilter('type_id', 'simple');
        $id=1;
        if ($id) {
            $data->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $id);
        }

        return $data;
    }
```

hope it will help you:-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply....

I am getting the following error when I use that.

report.CRITICAL: exception 'Exception' with message 'Report ID: webapi-568de5e300ce5; Message: Recoverable Error: Argument 2 passed to XXXXXXXX\Product\Model\Inventory::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory, instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory given

Thoughts?  Thanks again for the assist!

Comment: extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template, anwsers is edited please recheck the anweer code  if it work accept the answer so it helps others

Comment: No joy...  Thanks for the attempt though

Comment: answer was edited recheck or reuse the code now

Comment: Still the same error...  Thanks for the attempt to assist.  Much appreciated.

Comment: my end its working fine , jut copy paste it dont modify your code just copy pate attached code that it

Answer (score 1):

Regarding this error...

> CRITICAL: exception 'Exception' with message 'Report ID: webapi-568de5e300ce5; Message: Recoverable Error: Argument 2 passed to XXXXXXXX\Product\Model\Inventory::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory, instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactor

What's happening here is that the called block within var/generation has the older version of your current block. Magento cache system is crazy here. Easy fix tho. Go to ROOT/VAR/GENERATION/ Delete all folders there. It would be regenerated (Refresh) once you load the page.

For a cleaner fix. Go to SHELL, on your root directory type

```
$ php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

This will refresh all cache and regenerate al magento modules along custom module. Same as deleting VAR/GENERATION folders.

Hope it helps.